Alien invasion with a barrier on Earth
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie or probably a series about some kind of alien invasion.
I vaguely remember some parts: there was some kind of barrier on earth with aliens of the other side and at some point planes got to the alien side. I think that the barrier was expanding to include more and more of the earth. I also remember that the aliens abducted some people, and one was found wandering around near a water supply. Scientists examined him and found he had some poison in him; it was an alien ploy to poison the water supply. The aliens used human livers to do something, maybe filter some kind of enzyme...
The series (movie) was probably from the late 90's/early 2000's. If any of you have an idea, I'll be happy!

I think you're describing the Invasion: Earth miniseries from 1998.  It had a barrier:

An amorphous mountain of alien tentacles and design appears on the
  outskirts of Kirkhaven, and it begins expanding, swallowing up and
  absorbing all the surrounding organic matter and transporting it back
  to the nDs' home.

There are scenes of captured humans in agony inside the net.  The aliens kidnap them

in order to use them as living batteries.

Regarding a wandering human and a water supply:

The previously escaped NATO officer is running amok in the
  countryside. He drives to a reservoir some miles away, cuts his
  brachial artery and throws himself into the dam, where he bleeds to
  death.

This was to infect whoever drank the water, not to poison them. 

Trying to find "Invasion: Earth", sounds like it is it.
update soon. Thanks!

Yup, that's the series that gave me the willies all those years ago. Thank you!
